# d3 read input value

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to append an input html element with d3 and read the text value when it is changed:

```
$scope.addField = function (parent) {
        parent.append("br");
        parent.append("input")
            .attr("type", "input")
            .attr("placeholder", "Add a comment ...")
            .property("value", function (value) {
                console.log("value: " + value);     // logs: "value: undefined"
            })
            .text(function (value) {
                console.log("text: " + value);      // logs: "text: undefined"
            })
            .on("input", function (value) {
                console.log("oninput: "+ value)     // logs: "oninput: undefined"
            })
            .attr("id", ID_PREFIX + $scope.selection.id)
            .attr("value", "hallo")
            .on("change", function(d, i) {
                console.log("change: " + d + " " + i); // logs: change: undefined 0
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    const elem = d3.select("#" + ID_PREFIX + $scope.selection.id)
                                    .select("input");
                    console.log(elem);
                    // returns the html element but without the proper text information
                    $scope.setAnnotationComment({item: $scope.selection}, $scope.comment);
                });
            });
        parent.append("br");
};
```

So I am not able to get the changed value of the input field. Even assigning the input field a unique id and getting the html element with d3 by the unique id does not return a field "text", "value" or something similiar. When I examine the html with the chrome console, the input tag is just the following:

```
<input type="input" placeholder="Add a comment ...">
```

So no value attribute is assigned.

Is there another possibility? I want to avoid to select all input fields like:

```
d3.selectAll('input')
```

**Update:**
Here is an updated version of the JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/jeannedark/8e96hef6/7
Is this use case with d3 possible? If not what is the best way/ framework to achieve this, without to append a plane html element. I really appreciated the d3 style of adding attributes etc.

Comment: Could you make this a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for my very late response. Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jeannedark/8e96hef6/5/

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem drove me crazy until I was scrolling through the [D3js docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/API.md) searching for something else, and came upon this:

> Some HTML elements have special properties that are not addressable using attributes or styles, such as a form field’s text value and a checkbox’s checked boolean.

Use [`selection.property(name[, value])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_property) to get the data you need.